# Google-Playservices not getting linked to my project

Tags: android, eclipse

### What i have:

- I have a project that is already developed that runs googlemaps, so i
  have used play-services library.

### What i am doing:

- I have imported this project that i developed 2months ago
- Now i have reset my system with new os-downloaded latest sdk with
  latest playservices, I have imported playservices from sdk
  folder(copied) and linked it with my project as library project

### What is happening:

No matter how many time i link it is not getting linked

Also i have error at my project manifest

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

**Error as::** `error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').`

***I have cleaned the eclipse, restarted it .....still no effect !***

[image: Snapshot of where i can see lib is not getting linked]

---

### Note:

1. but if i create a sample project and link it, its getting properly
   linked !
2. This is happening only to the project that i developed 2 months ago

---

### Buildpath snapshot

[image]

Comment: Try reimporting the google maps project and adding it again to the build path.

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski .... adding to build path ? ...... is it different from the procedure i have shown above ?

Comment: No it's not. Just do it after reimporting libproject again. Also go to Order and Export in Java Build Path and check if the library is present or missing.

Comment: Also the api version comparability , sometimes api version mismatch they show an error. I'm also handle this error.

Comment: @Michał Szydłowski  ... please check the snapshot of buildpath i added .... i cannot see anything related to playservices ?

Comment: @ User786 ..... how u resolved this ? ..... is it because i need to update my api-level to maximum in sdk ?

Comment: Well that snapshot is hardly helpful, as I cannot see if a library is missing

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski ... i have added a clear view

Comment: Okay then its correctly referenced. Then it seems to me that the project is not compatible with your currend Android build tools (uses an older version). What you can do is set the projects target SDK to the ones you have currently installed.

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski ... I tried the fixes .... still having the same issue !

Comment: This is indeed a pain in the ass every time it happens. The last resort, if you are pressed on time, is to start a new clean project (with correctly configured google play services), and move classes or copy-paste the code one after another, checking every time if it works.

Comment: which api version did you use ?

Comment: But keep in mind that this is just a workaround, not a solution, and you should really avoid doing this in general.

Comment: @User786 ..... i had used maximum level as a higher one 21 .... now i have 14 but as  Michał Szydłowski suggested i changed min & max to 14 ...still it didnt solve my problem :(

Comment: Problem is that library is not added at all ...thats causing the problem ... this is not happening if i make a dummy project !

Comment: Min can stay the same. The target API is the key.